# after rotation and clip of a div hover is triggered wrong in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cosoroaba/nCEwv/

HTML:

```
<div id="square">
    <div class="corner-wrapper">
        <div id="ctr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#square {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
}
.corner-wrapper{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  
          transform: rotate(45deg);
    clip: rect(0px, 141.421px, 70.7107px, 0px);
    height: 141.421px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20.7107px;
    top: -20.7107px;
    width: 141.421px;
}
#ctr{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);  
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: 20.7107px;
    top: 20.7107px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

#ctr:hover{
    background-color: green;
}

#ctr:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I'm rotating the wrapper in one direction and the content in the opposite direction, then cutting the wrapper in half using `clip`, to achieve a "triangle"-div

which works well on FF,Chrome and Opera

but there is this issue in IE9 http://www.screenr.com/ikos

hover is triggered on the content in IE9 even if it would be hidden by the wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd refactor your code, there's a lot of unnecessary transformations going on, and if you change the size of your container your have to recalculate everything. I haven't checked in IE9 but this should work:

```
<div id="square">
        <div id="ctr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#square {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
}

#ctr{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);  
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
       -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

#ctr:hover{
    background-color: green;
}

#ctr:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/exKJK/

Comment: I had the extra rotation so I can add content/styles as usual to the inner div. I guess I'll rotate my background sprites ( http://i.imgur.com/PPdHQ.png ) in Photoshop then, so the browser will rotate it back